# What formulas to use for Estimate at Completion calculation?

Tags: management

I am not sure what formula to use to calculate EAC in next circumstances.

- When future budget estimates do not change. Is it correct to use EAC = AC + ETC?
- When future costs continue at the same spending rate. Is it correct to use EAC=BAC/CPI?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When future budget estimates do not change, the formula is EAC = AC + WR or EAC = AC + (BAC-EV).  Using ETC I believe indicates a revised estimate of remaining work.  Even if some use ETC to represent the baselined remaining work, using WR or BCWR will make it crystal clear.

Second bullet is yes.